# Flutter Web Scraping RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: flutter

I am making a quiz application by pulling data from the site. I could not solve the Range Error error I received in this process. Friends There are 50 items in 'items'. I guess forEach doesn't understand if it's finished. How can I do it? So it gives this error. I tried using for but I don't understand how to do it. RRangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0 Please help me

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:get/get.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
    
    import '../../../models/sorular.dart';
    import 'bitisekran/bitis_ekrani.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(sorubir());
    
    class sorubir extends StatefulWidget {
      const sorubir({super.key});
      @override
      State<sorubir> createState() => _sorubirState();
    }
    
    class _sorubirState extends State<sorubir> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              leading: BackButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              title: Text('Güncel Çıkmış Sorular'),
            ),
            body: sorubirIskele(),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class sorubirIskele extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<sorubirIskele> createState() => _sorubirIskeleState();
    }
    
    _sorubirIskeleState benimTestim = _sorubirIskeleState();
    class _sorubirIskeleState extends State<sorubirIskele> {
      List<Sorular> sorular = [];
      var soruIndex = 0;
      bool isLoading = false;
      var url = Uri.parse('https://www.ehliyettestleri.com/coz/24ha2023e');
    
      Future getData() async {
        setState(() {
          isLoading = true;
        });
        var res = await http.get(url);
        final String body = utf8.decode(res.bodyBytes);
        final document = parser.parse(body);
        var response = document
            .getElementsByClassName('items')[0]
            .getElementsByClassName('mtq_question mtq_scroll_item-1')
            .forEach((element) {
          setState(() {
            sorular.add(Sorular(
              soruno: element.children[0].text.toString(),
              sorugetir: element.children[1].text.toString(),
              imggetir:
                  element.querySelector('p > img')?.attributes['src'].toString(),
              agetir: element.children[2].children[1].children[0].children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              bgetir: element.children[2].children[1].children[1].children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              cgetir: element.children[2].children[1].children[2].children[1].text
                  .toString(),
              dgetir: element.children[2].children[1].children[3].children[1].text
                  .toString(),
            ));
          });
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you better provide more information about your flutter doctor and pubspec detail. Secondly, the problem here is `document.getElementsByClassName('items')[0]`, it **can not** find any class named `items` in html DOM.
Moreover the url should parse like this `final url = Uri.tryParse('www.ehliyettestleri.com/coz/24ha2023e');`.

Comment: `dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  get: ^4.6.5
  http: ^0.13.4
  html: ^0.15.4
  slide_countdown: ^0.6.0
  get_it: ^7.6.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0`

Comment: finds 'items'[]..getElementByClassName('mtq_question mtq_scroll_item-1').

Comment: Are you running on web platform?

Comment: I don't see any errors with your example on android platform. If you are running on web platform. It could be error because the http request return your own index.html file

Comment: It gives an error while navigating and shuts down after 1-2 seconds.

Comment: If you are running on web platform. Your request was surely blocked by CORS. You should try to run your Flutter web application with this command `flutter run -d chrome --web-browser-flag "--disable-web-security"`.